# How do I get this vector field effect on an image?

Tags: software-recommendation, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, effects

I recently came across an image in which there was a photo of horses running and (what appears to be) a vector field:
[image]
it looks like they may have taken a screenshot of an edit mode in whatever software was used, does anybody have any ideas on how to replicate this effect?